# What is the best way to perform multiple operations in a Knex transaction

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, transactions, knex.js

I'm relatively new to knex and transactions. Basically I have to perform a bunch of batch inserts and updates across different POSTGRES tables and wanted to understand the best possible way to do it.
Is the following a correct approach for this? I'm especially struggling with the batch-update part.

```
let fieldsToInsert = [{name:'Mike', age: 57, weight:66, gender:'M'}, ...]
let _user = {user_id:99, city:6}
return db.transaction(trx => {
            return trx.insert(fieldsToInsert)
            .into("users")
            .then(() => {
                const queries = fieldsToInsert.map((user) => {
                    db("biodata").update({"name": user.name}).where({"id": user.age})
                })
                return Promise.all(queries)
            }).then(() => {
                const queries = fieldsToInsert.map((user) => {
                    db("weight_and_gender".update({"weight": user.weight, "gender": user.gender}))
                })
                return Promise.all(queries)
            })   
        }).catch((err) => {
            console.log(err)
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

```
await db.transaction(async trx => {
  const insertedRows = await trx('users').insert(fieldsToInsert).returning('*');
  for (let row in insertedRow) {
    await trx('biodata').update({name : row.name}).where('id', row.id);       
    await trx('weight_and_gender').update({weight : row.weight, gender: row.gender}).where('id', row.id);       
  }
});
```

Trying to run updates in parallel with `Promise.all` does not help anything. DB driver will buffer those anyways and run them sequentially in either way if they are executed in the same transaction.